# How to create a single drop down for multiple data types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3 and I need to create a single drop down list which contains items that relate to multiple database tables.

Normally, if I need to do a drop down list for a single data type I can easily use the ID as the "value" for each drop down `option` and would do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedID, Model.GetMyList())
```

But now I want to mix up multiple data types. So lets say for this example I want to create a single list to represent something like "Owner" and this can be either a "User" or a "Customer". In this example, both User and Customer are separate database tables and therefore the ID value alone is not enough to identify them correctly.

So what are the best ways to achieve such functionality?

Straight off the top of my head, my first thoughts are to create a "custom" value string which could then be parsed server side to work out the ID and data type, something like...

```
"USER|1"
"CUSTOMER|1"
```

I know I can make this work, but am I making this more complicated than it needs to be? Is there a built-in or advised way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has come up with anything better, I can confirm that my original idea (as unwanted as it was) did the job.

When setting the value of the select options, a custom string should be created that can easily be parsed server side, this was achieved using a pipe separating the TYPE of entity, and the ID, for example:

```
"USER|1"
"USER|2"
"CUSTOMER|1"
"CUSTOMER|2"
```

Once the selected value is passed to the server, it can then be parsed something like the following:

```
string option = "USER|1";
string[] values = option.Split('|');
string entityType = values[0];
int entityId = Int.Parse(values[1]);
```

which can then be used something like this:

```
if(entityType == "USER")
   UpdateUser(entityId);
else//CUSTOMER
   UpdateCustomer(entityId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model can you not do something like this:-

```
public class Model
{
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public List<MyList> ListCollection { get; set; }

    public class MyList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So then when you are checking which list item is selected you also have access to the "Owner" field which will tell you what table it belongs to ?

Comment: I dont think this will work. Owner doesn't appear to be related to a list item. Unless you meant for me to use `Value` as the data type? But I am not sure that MVC will be able to bind such a complex object anyway.... or maybe it can?